# What is a well received question?

Tags: support, questions, badges

The criterion for 'curious' badge is to post 5 'well received' questions. Although the answer to this is probably quite simple, still, I do know what well-received means in practice.

Comment: You can find the answer on the SE Meta site: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges.  In general, *our* meta site is for questions about *our* site specifically.  Issues that would likely pertain to many other sites, too-such as badge requirements--usually already have answers on SE meta and if not should be discussed there.

Comment: @whuber Thank-you for the information. The information about badges I did not know was a common feature to all SE sites, I had assumed that the criteria for badges were site dependent. I had also searched the SE meta site for the answer prior to asking it here, and did not find the link you were so kind as to provide here. Perhaps there is a lesson to be learned from my ignorance. That would be how somehow provide for better information retrieval.

Comment: I found the information by going to the [Meta site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) and searching on [curious badge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=curious%20badge) and sorting the results to see the newest first.

Comment: Hi @Carl. Why don't you accept Andre's answer here? Does it not resolve your question?

Comment: @amoeba Because I did not see it. Thanks for the heads-up, I see it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Qualifying for the curious/inquisitive/socratic badges requires accumulating [good asking days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234966/does-a-closed-question-cancel-out-that-days-valid-questions). One good asking day means:

asking at least one positively-scored question (aka "well received question") without having another question negatively-scored, closed or deleted on that day.

For curious one needs 5 good asking days; inquisitive 30 and socratic 100. Also, the [question record](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges) needs to be positive.